# Roblox regen script

Tags: roblox

Im trying to make it so after a player touches a certain brick it falls,that part works.But what I want it to do is to respawn after a set amount of time and the old one be destroyed.Im trying to make an obby with falling bricks.I have no clue what to do

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy, all you need to do is add a `wait()` and then once it's waited said amount of time make it change the position of the block back to what it was. Here:

```
function onTouched(humanoid)
    wait(3)
    script.Parent.Position = Vector3.new(0.57, 1.2, 1.23)
end
script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouched)
```

Put this script in the brick you want 'regenerated' and change the wait and position to what you want.